# Doctrine OneToMany relationship not retrieving data

Tags: symfony, doctrine, one-to-many

I have 3 entities:

```
class Associationprocurators
{
    /**
     * @var binary
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AssociationProcuratorId", type="binary", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $associationprocuratorid;

    /**
     * @var  ArrayCollection<Procuratorsituationhistory>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Procuratorsituationhistory", mappedBy="associationprocuratorid", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $procuratorsituationhistory;


    /**
     * @var  ArrayCollection<Addresses>
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Addresses", mappedBy="associationprocuratorid", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $addressesarray;
```

And the other two related entities:

```
class Procuratorsituationhistory
{
    /**
     * @var binary
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="SituationChangeId", type="binary", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $situationchangeid;

    /**
     * @var \Associationprocurators
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Associationprocurators", inversedBy="procuratorsituationhistory")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AssociationProcuratorId", referencedColumnName="AssociationProcuratorId")
     * })
     */
    private $associationprocuratorid;


class Addresses
{
    /**
     * @var binary
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="AddressId", type="binary", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $addressid;

    /**
     * @var \Associationprocurators
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Associationprocurators", inversedBy="addressesarray")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="AssociationProcuratorId", referencedColumnName="AssociationProcuratorId")
     * })
     */
    private $associationprocuratorid;
```

The problem is when the fetch option in the two OneToMany relationships is set to LAZY (in both, procuratorsituationhistory and addressesarray) only the first OneToMany retrieve the data, the second remains empty. If I set one of them to EAGER it's working ok.

Can't I have two LAZY OneToMany relationships in the same entity?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it is possible and you don't need to use EAGER. You just need to make joins in your repositories (doc here : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)

Comment: Thanks @vinceAmstoutz, but could you give an example? Do you mean that I can let both OneToMany relationships be LAZY and change my Repository?

Comment: Exactly ! You have an example on the documentation and plenty on stackoverflow. Sorry but I hav'nt time to this :/